# while loop only going through once

Tags: python

I have a piece of code here that is supposed to loop until the user types in a 0. However it does not loop more than once.

```
 while temp==1:
        cachv = input("Enter CACH value: ")
        mmaxv = input("Enter MMAX value: ")
        inpuv = [cachv, mmaxv]
        inpuvd= np.reshape(inpuv, (-1, 2))
        test = clf.predict(inpuvd)
        if test == 0:
            print('The performance will be high')
        else:
            print('The performance will be low')
        temp = input('Retest? 1 for Y, 0 for N: ')
    print('done')
```

The temp variable is first set to 1. When i enter 1 to retry it does not retry

```
Enter CACH value: 1
Enter MMAX value: 2
The performance will be low
Retest? 1 for Y, 0 for N: 1
done
```

This is what it looks like

Comment: `input` returns a string. `'1'` is not `==` to `1` in Python.

Comment: When you assign `temp` using `input` it is a string, not an integer. So the comparison of the while loop fails. Simply change to `int(input())`

Comment: @RobinZigmond
Thanks guys for the quick response

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function input() returns a string object, which means that your temp variable becomes a string.
therefore you are testing `"1" == 1` which is false

You should update your temp variable as follows:

```
temp = int(input(" ... "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `temp = input('Retest? 1 for Y, 0 for N: ')`
to `temp = int(input('Retest? 1 for Y, 0 for N: '))`